# Transfer Data to specific Excel Sheet

Tags: excel, vba, transfer

I am trying to transfer the data to specific sheet at last row but not able to data transferring but after some empty cells in sheet b c d e help needed to solve data is transferring in each sheet but not at next empty cell:

```
 Sub transferData()
      Application.ScreenUpdating = False
      'Dim myData As Worksheet, ItemA As Worksheet, ItemB As Worksheet, ItemC As Worksheet, ItemD As 
       Worksheet, ItemE As Worksheet
      Dim ItemName As String
      Dim price As Long, qty As Long

      Dim r1 As Long, r2 As Long, erow As Long, lastrow As Long
      r1 = 2
      r2 = 2
      Sheets(Array("Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4", "Sheet5", "Sheet6")).Select
      Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
      Cells.Select
      Selection.ClearContents
      Sheets(Array("Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4", "Sheet5", "Sheet6")).Select
      Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
      range("A1").Select
      ActiveCell.Value = "Item"
      range("B1").Select
      ActiveCell.Value = "Price"
      range("C1").Select
      ActiveCell.Value = "Quantity"

       MYDATA.Activate

      Do While Cells(r2, 1) <> ""
      ItemName = Cells(r2, 1).Value
      price = Cells(r2, 2).Value

      qty = Cells(r2, 3).Value

       p = Worksheets.Count
       For q = 1 To p
       If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(q).CodeName = UCase(ItemName) Then
       Worksheets(q).Activate
       erow = Worksheets(q).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
       Cells(r2, 1).Value = ItemName
      Cells(r2, 2).Value = price
       Cells(r2, 3).Value = qty
       r2 = r2 + 1


        enter code here

       End If
       Next q
       MYDATA.Activate
        Loop
       Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: sir,i want to transfer all row of data in range "a1" to a sheet named equal to range means in range "a1" i have some data which is named same as sheet name is cell name mathches with sheet name i want copy rows and paste in the particular sheet plz suggest

Comment: This is a new question. To ensure data integrity, please start a new post.

Answer (score 0):

A few comment:

1. Adding some indentation will make your code more understandable
2. Avoid using `Range().Select` then `ActiveCell.Value=xxx`, it will be very slow. Simply use `Range().Value = xxx`.  This applies to other entities such as worksheets, cells, etc.
3. Within your `For...Next` loop, `r2` should be replaced by `erow` in order to copy your value to the other worksheets.

Comment: thank you very much its worked  i am new to vba still learing

Comment: thank you very much its worked i am new to vba still learing

Comment: sir,i want to transfer all row of data in range "a1" to a sheet named equal to range means in range "a1" i have some data which is named same as sheet name is cell name mathches with sheet name i want copy rows and paste in the particular sheet plz suggest